# Need guidance on RewriteRule for Opencart Site

Tags: opencart

I have built a new Opencart shop in a sub-directory of an old root domain :
ie. *http://www.old-domain.com/opencart*
Now I have a new domain name which now points ok to the sub-directory:
ie. *http://www.new-domain.com* (I have updated both config.php files correctly)
However, clicking on any internal link shows the old-domain url in the address bar.

So I need guidance in replacing (rewriting) the old name with the new one - whilst still retaining the correct paths etc.
I have done a fair amount of research, and tried this and that in my htaccess without success.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that OpenCart was installed on the old domain thus this URL address is set as constant (define) within its config files.

If You want to change it, go open these two files:

- `<OPENCART_ROOT>/config.php`
- `<OPENCART_ROOT>/admin/config.php`

and edit these defines:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://olddomain.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://olddomain.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://olddomain.com/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://olddomain.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://olddomain.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://olddomain.com/image/');
```

to

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://newdomain.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://newdomain.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://newdomain.com/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://newdomain.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://newdomain.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://newdomain.com/image/');
```

(the config file within the root wouldn't have that `/admin/` URLs part...)

This should solve Your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I have already updated both config.php files to reflect the new url....!!!....
I have limited knowledge, but I believe I need to put some 'rewrite' code in my htaccess file..and that is what I am having difficulty with...thanks again

Comment: And what version of OC are You using? In older versions of OC (prior to `1.5.0`) the URL was stored within a DB table `setting`... Anyway if You have installed OpenCart into a subfolder make sure in Your `.htaccess` file You have set the `RewriteBase` to `/subfolder/` (instead of pure `/`).

Comment: OC version is 1.5.4.1 and the RewriteBase is in fact set to the /subfolder....thanks for trying to help.

Comment: To assist getting a solution, I'll put the question another way.

I simply need to replace:
www.oldsite.com/path/path/etc

with:
www.newsite.com/path/path/etc

Thanks.

Comment: If the URLs comming from OpenCart are pointing to old domain and You'll add a rewrite to new domain You'll end up with any request being redirected, and this is not quite OK, I guess. Do not cure the symptoms but the origin...

Comment: Ok thanks shadyyx..so the next question might be "could you give me a clue as to what the 'origin' is likely to be ?"....

Comment: Comment: The issue now solved.
Even though the new domain name points to a sub-directory, the htaccess file needs the RewriteBase instruction to be set to 'Root'
ie. RewriteBase /
Sorry, my error....thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need in your .htaccess so visitors to the old domain will be redirected to the new one.  The R=301 assumes you've permanently moved to the new domain.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^opencart/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To make sure that all internal links are pointing to the new domain you need to

1 - Update your config.php files (which you have already done

2 - Replace all occurrences within content (information pages, product descriptions, banners. etc) of your old domain with the new one. phpMyAdmin has a handy search feature to find them all if you have access to it.

3 - There *might* still be references to your old domain hard-coded into your php & tpl files, but there shouldn't be - if there are you'll have to change these too (or better still fix them to use the constants defined in config.php)

Just a warning on #2 - if you are planning on changing these directly within phpMyAdmin don't update any serialised arrays unless you know what they are doing e.g.

```
a:1:{i:1;a:1:{i:0;s:28:"http://olddomain.com/opencart"}}
```